# Not able to setCookie in Testcafe

Tags: testing, cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have set the cookie by using below method in testcafe, once the cookie executes in the site, not able to see the old experience neither new experience also

**setCookie("value=1;max-age=4560000;domain=.abc.com;path=/");**

```
    Testcafe Version: 1.15.3
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookies management functionality was introduced in version 1.19:

https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released

You need to update your TestCafe version as it lacks this feature.